# Ubuntu in VMWare Alt-key issues

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mac

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Macbook (4.1) running Lion.

I have chosen the Swedish (Macintosh) keyboard layout and it's working pretty good. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> etc. are all working as in OSX.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> is not working as I want though.

How can I make it function just as in OSX? So, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> => | etc.
Right now nothing happens (brings up dashboard menu when Alt is clicked).

I'm very new to Ubuntu and I have tried to change the Options in the Keyboard Layout settings but I can't find the correct settings. Even tried with Xmodmap, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set 3rd level select button to "Any Alt-key" in the keyboard layout options